# uninitialized constant LoginController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is my controller

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def create
    student = Student.find_by(email: params[:logins][:email].downcase)
    if student && student.authenticate(params[:logins][:password])
      session[:student_id] = student.id
      flash[:notice] = "You have successfully logged in"
      redirect_to student
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "Something was wrong with your login information"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:student_id] = nil
    flash[:notice] =  "You have successfully logged out"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

Here is my route

```
 get 'login', to: 'logins#new'
  post 'login', to: 'logins#create'
  delete 'logout', to: 'login#destroy'
```

And when I click logout button it is giving Routing error uninitialized constant LoginController

Here is the github link for the project [link](https://github.com/git4ruby/University-App)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo error in your routes:

Change delete 'logout', to: 'login#destroy' to delete 'logout', to: 'logins#destroy'

Comment: The sneaky little `s` strikes again! Rails is very particular about pluralization, so it's always worth double checking these.